# msbuild in CI server

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, nuget

I'm a bit confused around msbuild and nuget tools in order to integrate them in a continous delivery line.

I've set up my CI server ([jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)) and my NuGet reporsitory ([myget](http://www.myget.org/))

Mainly, I need to hook several points inside the CI process:

- **On developer machine**: Do nothing, simply build and generate artifacts locally.
- **On CI Server**: Pushed commit on `develop`, `feature\*`, `hotfix\*` like branches.

  - When a commit is pushed on whichever of the above branches I would like to:

    1. Push the artifact on NuGet repository.

How could I get it using two single msbuild scripts?